# Angular, npm, nexus, and CI practices

Tags: angular, npm, deployment, nexus, dev-to-production

This post is an insight on `npm` for those of you who have a `maven` background.

In the `Java/maven` world, you build a source code to a jar, then you push your jar to Nexus. **All of this is done using `maven`**.
Eventually, your deployment tool retrieves your jar from where it was stored in Nexus, and delivers it to whatever environment it targeted.

Now I'm working on an Angular project and have a hard time, putting all the pieces together.

I understand I can publish my Angular project to an npm repository in Nexus. But what I will publish here will be an npm package, including a `package.json` file.
I understand I can build my Angular project to a `/dist` folder, and deliver this folder to an environment.

But now, I don't understand how it all make sense: with my `maven` background, I'm expecting to use `npm` to push the content of the `/dist` to Nexus!

What am I missing here? What are the good practices in this domain?

Comment: It's up to you and your needs. FWIW last time I was storing an Angular app in an artifact manager we would `ng build` the app in the CI pipeline and store the zipped content of `/dist`.

Comment: @Brad Larson : Thx dude

Comment: You could use a nexus [raw repository](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/raw-repositories) and upload the `dist/` using `webdav`, under an `[appname]/[version]/` directory. But again you would need to update somehow the `base-href` inside the landing page based on the location from which you want to serve it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research here is my understanding of the subject:

Once compiled using `ng build` your Angular project is no longer an npm project but a static web site.
You may no longer manage (in this case: "deploy" to Nexus) your project using `npm` like you would do with `maven`.

As such (quoting jonrsharpe's comment) you may zip the content of the `/dist` folder produced by `ng build` to distribute it.

At this point, if you wish to push it to a Nexus repository, you may use **maven deploy plugin**. But then your web site would be pushed to a maven repository.

Bottom line: it all depends on what you need to do.

I hope this helps.

Comment: How about publishing all your Angular components as an npm package? Then at some point in the CI/CD pipeline, you will assemble all those npme packages plus the static HTML page into an angular application.

Comment: Agreed, but this implies rebuilding your static site each time you deliver it, vs build once and deploy on every env.

Answer (score 1):

It is always feasible to use npm publish in the angular application **without** using a maven deploy plugin. You should first run ***ng build*** and then copy package.json to dist folder. You can create a specific build script that combine ***ng build*** and ***cp*** command of package.json to dist folder.

Issues: you should also provide publishConfig in package.json like this :

*"publishConfig": {
"registry": "https://your-nexus-url/repository/npm-registry/"
}*

Finally, you should add npm token to .npmrc file.

I have integrated this in a prod project with Jenkins and Nexus, I hope that it will be helpful.